# protractor .get is not a function when calling using local variable

Tags: javascript, protractor

Pls consider the below code:

```
//CL.DCBS_List_AllElements = $$('#directClassBased > option')


this.shouldMatchDCBSList = async function () {
        var DCBSItems = await CL.DCBS_List_AllElements;
        console.log('Test Text = '+await CL.DCBS_List_AllElements.get(3).getText());
        console.log('Test Text 2 = '+await DCBSItems.get(4).getText());
```

When I execute this piece of code, the first console.log (console.log('Test Text = '+await CL.DCBS_List_AllElements.get(3).getText());) return the text as expected. But for the next one, when I am using it as a variable ( "await DCBSItems.get(4).getText()" ) , it gives me the following error:

> Failed: DCBSItems.get is not a function

This is kind of strange as I could get the text returned before when I passed the elements using the parameters/variables. I spent many hours to fix it but its not working now. How can we fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

If you await an ElementArrayFinder, you will get an array of ElementFinders. See https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/element.ts#L535

When calling `ElementArrayFinder.get(index)`, Protractor will get the `index` in the ElementArrayFinder object. If you await an ElementArrayFinder, you will get an array. So in this case where you are using `DCBSItems`, instead of calling the `.get` you should call `await DCBSItems[4].getText()`.